# go-git how to generate patch for first commit?

Tags: git, go, go-git

I have following code

```
    commitIter, err := r.Log(&git.LogOptions{From: commit.Hash})
    CheckIfError(err)

    err = commitIter.ForEach(func(c *object.Commit) error {
        parent, err := c.Parent(0)

        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }

        patch, err := c.Patch(parent)
        CheckIfError(err)

        fmt.Println(patch)

        return nil
    })
```

it iterates over all commits and generates patch for each of them, using reference to parent. But first commit doesn't have parent then I can't generate patch. Is there any workaround like passing empty commit?

I was searching and I found [open pull request on archived `go-git` repository](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/issues/868).

Comment: I've no answer but I'd try to call `c.Patch(commit.GetCommit(plumbing.ZeroHash))`

Comment: `object.GetCommit` requires two arguments, first is `storer.EncodedObjectStorer`. What I should pass?

Comment: The examples in `go-git` suggest this is "a repository". I mean, some object which is returned by a call which "opens" a repository.

Comment: @kostix I can't solve this :( I created [new issue](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/issues/281)

Answer (score 0):

Using object trees instead of commits allows you to generate a patch for the first commit.

For example:

```golang
    commitTree, err := commit.Tree()
    if err == nil {
        parentTree := &object.Tree{}
        if commit.NumParents() != 0 {
            parent, err := commit.Parents().Next()
            if err == nil {
                parentTree, err = parent.Tree()
                if err == nil {
                    parentTree.Patch(commitTree)
                }
            }
        } else {
            parentTree.Patch(commitTree)
        }
    }
```